# SAML/oauth2/openid-connect login via proxy as another user

Tags: proxy, oauth2, sso, saml

I manage a set of service providers (SP1, SP2, SP3, etc), and we currently have this SAML SSO flow working where the SP causes a POST submit to the SAML IDP with an XML SAML request which includes an SP SAML Endpoint. The SAML IDP returns a SAMLresponse token to the browser which sends it to the SP SAML endpoint for verification:
[image]

Each SP has Apache httpd/mod_auth_openidc redirecting to a Keycloak instance which has a SAML IDP configured for auth.   Keycloak ultimately interacts with the SP using Oauth2/OpenID-connect and a JWT to mod_auth_openidc.   Works great.  Keycloak shields all the SAML work from the SP application which understands Oauth2/OpenID-Connect JWTs....

Now I have been tasked to write an intelligent proxy which sits between the UserBrowser and the Service Providers that are running keycloak.  **Users will NOT be able to directly access the SP's anymore** and will authenticate to the Proxy instead.  The Proxy will then forward all requests from the users to one of the SPs each of which supplies different information.

However the SPs still need to know who the user is, and need to trust whoever tells it the userID.  They currently determine userID from the SAMLresponse/JWT provided by Keycloak to determine application access level.

Here is a diagram with the Intelligent Proxy inserted.

[image]

I have mulled this for a couple of weeks and cannot figure out what to do with that SAMLresponse the proxy receives.

I want to forward the SAMLresponse to SP/Keycloak and have it interact in the same fashion it does today.  I am thinking the SAMLResponse is 'signed' by the IDP and the Keycloak can still verify the signature and immediately trust the SAMLresponse, extract the User and determine that users role to return to the SP application.

One thing I have considered is to create an Oauth2 Client in Keycloak using 'client_credentials' grant and the proxy will use that client to authenticate and provide the SAMLresponse.  But how do I get Keycloak to verify/parse the SAMLresponse and respond to the SP application in the same manner as before?

Ultimately I believe mod_auth_openidc will hold the JWT and return a session cookie via the proxy to the user's browser.

I have tried to study various flows to get Keycloak to do this, but I haven't been successful yet.  My goal is to minimize the impact on the SPs and have the user's browser continue to get the needed session cookies from the SPs to be able to run the application.

Confused?  So am I!

Thanks for any help you can provide.